How to modify a Z Math Surface after it has been created?
After having followed the short tutorial of how to create Z Math Surfaces, I would like to change the underlying function, once the element
has been created (For example, I want to exchange a coefficient in the function).
How do I do that?

I don't think you can modify it after the fact. That add on is creating a normal mesh based on the function, not some special object that can be adjusted afterwards. I think you'd have to create a new one and not close the pop up until you are done

You can't, use geometry nodes instead.
